# ClickHouse: How to convert integer after toYYYYMMDD back to DateTime?

Tags: clickhouse

In ClickHouse `toYYYYMMDD` returns integer with year/month/day set positionally.

```
SELECT toYYYYMMDD(now())

┌─toYYYYMMDD(now())─┐
│          20211112 │
└───────────────────┘
```

How to convert this integer back to Date type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `parseDateTimeBestEffort`: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions/#parsedatetimebesteffort

```
SELECT parseDateTimeBestEffort(toString(20211112))


┌─parseDateTimeBestEffort(toString(20211112))─┐
│                         2021-11-12 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

starting from 21.12

```sql
select toDate('20211111')
┌─toDate('20211111')─┐
│         2021-11-11 │
└────────────────────┘
```

It's impossible for numbers, because number already is used `toDate(number_of_dates_from_1970)`

```sql
SELECT toDate(18942)
┌─toDate(18942)─┐
│    2021-11-11 │
└───────────────┘
```

There is no function `fromYYYYMMDD` because nobody asked before.